# How to process multiple url simultaneously using python request libry

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests

prefer sticking with the Python Requests library. Although I've searched on Google and Stack Overflow, I've only found solutions involving asyncio or similar library, without any clear guidance on combining it with the python Requests library.

Here's what I want to do: I have a list of 1000 URLs, and I want to work on 100 URLs together in each batch. This means I'd loop through the list 10 times, processing 100 URLs in each loop. This approach is much faster than processing each URL one by one. Now, what if I have 1001 URLs? How can I make this work for odd quantities like 10001 or 507?"

```
def req_proxy(url: str, http_flag: bool):
    response = requests.get(url, verify=http_flag)
    return response


url_list = [] #assume I have 1k url
for link in url_list:
    res = req_proxy(link,http_flag=True)
    print(res.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your title and the example you provided seem to be talking about two different things. If you need concurrency your best best is to use asyncio. If you just want to parse URLs in batches, that would be a different thing.

```py
# you can choose any number you want
# you can also make it dynamic, e.g. depending on the number of URLs
BATCH_SIZE = 100

url_list = [] #assume I have 1k url
offset = 0
while url_list(offset:offset + BATCH_SIZE):
    for link in url_list[offset:offset + BATCH_SIZE]:
        res = req_proxy(link,http_flag=True)
        print(res.text)
    offset += BATCH_SIZE
```

This will loop till the end of the list with batches of size `BATCH_SIZE`, the last list will be smaller in case the length of the URLs is not a multiple of `BATCH_SIZE`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to process multiple url simultaneously，

you can use **threading** or **multiprocessing**.

for loop can not get url simultaneously. it is still one by one

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html